# VBA assigns incorrect value to variable

Tags: vba, excel

I have a function in VBA, which is a part of a bigger setup. The function resides inside a `Class Module`, and is basically just a glorified subtraction. I wondered why I got some weird results, so I (over-)simplified the function for debugging purposes. It turns out, that one of the variables isn't assigned the value that it should, but rather some seemingly random value. How can a simple assign go so wrong?

And even weirder, why does it not always it assigns the incorrect value? It only happens sometimes. Other times it is correct. And occationally it seems like nothing is evaluated at all, and the function just returns 0 (zero).

From all I can see it cannot be an issue with my code, but rahter with the way VBA works (behind the scenes). But as long as I do not understand it, it is quite difficult to mitigate.

**Code:**

```
Public Property Get MySubtractionFunction() As Double
    Dim tmpValue1 As Double
    Dim tmpValue2 As Double
    Dim tmpOutput As Double

    'When debugging, sometimes CDbl(Me.Value2) evaluates to approximately 18.000
    'However tmpValue2 evaluates to approximately 10.000
    tmpValue1 = CDbl(Me.Value1)
    tmpValue2 = CDbl(Me.Value2) 

    tmpOutput = tmpValue1 - tmpValue2 'Breakpoint is set at this line
    tmpOutput = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(tmpOutput , tmpValue1)

    'Return output
    MySubtractionFunction= tmpOutput 

End Property
```

**Update 1**
When I hover the mouse over `Me.Value2` before reaching the breakpoint, it actually shows the value that is assigned to `tmpValue2`. If I then remove the mouse, and hover back over `Me.Value2` again, then it shows a different value. How can a property value just change like that, without any code being executed?

**Update 2**
Maybe I should mention that the problem only arises when I use the Class Object inside a loop. It is called like this:

```
For i = 1 To 1000
    Dim myObject As myClass
    Set myObject = New myClass
    'Some initialization
    result = myObject.MySubtractionFunction
    'A bunch of other stuff
    Set myObject = Nothing
Next i
```

Comment: what type `Me.Value1` and `Me.Value2` are? Are they of `String` type? And if so, what's their actual value before conversion to `Double`?

Comment: Both the properties are of type `Double` already. I just added the `CDbl` as a debugging attempt, it is not required.

Comment: It seems that you are calculating times values. Such values are notorious for being converted incorrectly. Look at how a value like `01:10:15` ends up as a Dbl in your user form.

Comment: The Get property is designed for Class modules. A UserForm is a class module only in some respects. I have had funny experiences with this property, though not like you do, and gave up the practise. I now declare the form in a normal code module and add whatever values I want to add before the Show command.

Comment: @Variatus the property resides in a pure Class Module (not a User Form). However the class module instance is created by a User Form. I don't know if that makes any difference...

Comment: Another approach: `Value2` is a property of the Range object. Try using another name for this variable.

Comment: You've left out some pretty important code - namely the code that actually assigns the values your property is using. You also haven't given any specifics at all as to how the results are wrong but I can tell you that VBA doesn't just make numbers up or change them without any code running (or a state loss).

Comment: @Rory you are correct. I had to leave some code out, as the amount of steps from input to my calculation is rather large. It turned out that the issue originated a lot earlier, in a different property. But once I inspected (mouse over) the property value, it somehow refreshed the value, making it quite confusing to debug. I will make an answer with my fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

As I mentioned, the property I had an issue with, was the last in a chain of many. All calling other properties of the class module (except the first in the chain). The problem originated quite early, and chained through all the steps.

The reason it was so difficult to identify, was that the property value which was initially incorrect, was updated when I hovered the mouse over the variable to inspect the variable, in debugging mode.

The solution was to expand all the steps in the chain, in a manner similar to that in the original post. This is not always required, since the problem only showed when I ran a multiple of calculations rapidly. But if anyone expeirence similar problems, I would suggest you try this fix.

**This did not work:**

```
Public Property Get myProperty() As Double
    myProperty = Me.someOtherProperty + Me.aThirdProperty
End Property
```

**This did:**

```
Public Property Get myProperty() As Double
    Dim tempSomeOtherProperty As Double
    Dim tempAThirdProperty As Double
    Dim tempResult As Double

    tempSomeOtherProperty = Me.someOtherProperty
    tempAThirdProperty = Me.aThirdProperty
    tempResult = tempSomeOtherProperty + tempAThirdProperty

    myProperty = tempResult

End Property
```

Answer (score 0):

All computer languages have a huge problem, when they are dealing with doubles (floating points). Thus, in C#, you should use `decimal` to avoid this problem. In Excel, you should round.

Take a look at what Microsoft says about it:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/78113/floating-point-arithmetic-may-give-inaccurate-results-in-excel

Comment: I have tried added `Round(<value>, 2)` instead of `CDbl` with no luck. I also tried `Round()` inside the properties, before returning the property value.

Comment: Can you switch the `double` to `long` just to see what happens?

Comment: `Me.Value1` is probably a textbox or another control which basically deals in strings. So, you are converting a string to double, in plain text, you convert the most imprecise arithmetic expression into the most precise Excel has to offer. But I suspect that is only half the problem. The other half would be if you are, in fact, converting a time, expressed as a string value, to a double. Both, your coding and the information you provide here, are too imprecise to permit a working answer. Lift the veil over what `Me.Value1` is and what value it holds.

Comment: @Variatus `Me.Value1` comes from the property defined as `Property Get Value1() As Double`. So I don't think the issue arises from a conversion error. At least not at that point.

Comment: @Vityata I tried changing `CDbl` to `CLng`. This doesnt change anything.

Comment: Try to use public variables to pass `Value1` and `Value2` and see if the error persists. Look at the source of those variables. Believe me, it isn't that VBA or Excel don't know how to calculate. Therefore the error must be due to something else, and why not the variables themselves?

Comment: @Variatus I know that it doesn't fail at anything as simple as a subtraction (or assignment). I beleive the problem arises much earlier as there is a chain of properties passed and manipulated inside the object, before it gets to the function above. So I believe it is to do with the way VBA handles objects. I added some more details to the original post.